# app license testing

Tags: android, testing, licensing

I know I have to upload it to my developer account to test it fully but does that mean it will be available to download by everyone when I hit publish?

I want to test to make sure I have everything how I want it first before people can download it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to File>Export android application in eclipse, and use a non-debug keystore, the resulting .apk will be what everyone else will be downloading.  Putting this apk on a phone (by sideloading, using adb etc.) will have the same effect as a user downloading it from the market.

To sideload the apk to a device, use the following adb command with your device plugged in and USB debugging enabled:

```
adb install <path-to-apk>
```

Comment: Right I know that but I am talking more on the lines of testing the logic of how to handle the market licensing, like if it is licensed or not licensed.  If i understand correctly the only way to test that is to upload it to the market

Comment: You do not understand correctly. You do not have to upload an LVL-protected app in order to run LVL checks against it.

Comment: That did nothing different than if I ran it through eclipse to my device, I still get the same not-market-managed error